# Query exceeded resource limits in BigQuery GROUP BY on big data

Tags: google-bigquery, query-optimization

I have two tables -

**StringList** which has only one column

```
SearchString
abc
def
ghi
lmn
```

I have one other table **Phrase** with one column

```
Phrase
xyzabcefg
ddflkd
fdjkd
abcdefghi
extreme
```

I need an output table which will have two columns -

**SearchString** **Phrases**

Search string will be search string from first table and Phrases will be all data from 2nd table where Search string occurs in Phrase

Something like below -

```
SearchString Phrases
abc   [xyzabcefg, abcdefghi]
def   [abcdefghi]
ghi   [abcdefghi]
```

I am able to get the results but the query is not optimized at all, I have around 2.4 M records in 2nd table and 7.5K in 1st table.

I need to scale this query to 240M records in 2nd table but this query doesn't work even on 1.5 M records right now.

Gives following error -

**Query exceeded resource limits. 13256.532365742061 CPU seconds were used, and this query must use less than 9200.0 CPU seconds.**

I tried various things but no success. My current query is -

```
With first_batch as (
SELECT
a.Phrase,
b.SearchString
FROM `project-id.DS_WORK.Phrase`  a
join `project-id.DS_WORK.StringList` b
ON a.Phrase LIKE '%' || b.SearchString || '%' )
SELECT
first_batch.SearchString,
'[' || STRING_AGG(first_batch.Phrase) || ']' AS Phrases
FROM first_batch
GROUP BY first_batch.SearchString;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

I am thinking of using loops in User-defined functions but I first want to check if there is a simpler way to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the execution details for your query so we can check which part is consuming more processing power?

Comment: Edited the question to include image.

Comment: I did not see any abnormal activity through this execution log. Although, there are practices that make your query perform better such as select only the columns your desire, filter your data before joining and more. Here is the link for [documentation][https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview]. I created a new query which I believe it can be faster and thus do not exceed the CPU seconds, I will share in the next comment.

Comment: `DECLARE str1 ARRAY<STRING>;
SET str1 = (
SELECT  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT str order by str)  FROM test-proj-261014.bq_load_codelab.string
);

Select str, ARRAY_AGG(phrase) as phrases from project_id.data_set.string t1
cross join  project_id.data_set.phrase  t2 
where t1.str = REGEXp_EXTRACT(t2.phrase, t1.str)
group by str` . Remember to put back the back quotes when referencing the tables, I had to remove them due to formatting. Did it work for you?

Comment: I had only 1 column in both the tables.

Comment: Did you try the query I posted? Within the query ou can see that I only select one column in each table.

Comment: I tried your query, this is a very expensive query because of the cross join and regexp_Extract...

Query exceeded resource limits. 211542.26909996368 CPU seconds were used, and this query must use less than 9200.0 CPU seconds. at [11:1]

Answer (score 0):

In the BigQuery you should avoid using `group by` on a big data. The reason is the data are processed on distributed nodes that are small. Functions like group by or order by need all the data on one node that is not possible.

Try use window function instead. I would rewrite your query like

```
With first_batch as (
SELECT
a.Phrase,
b.SearchString
FROM `project-id.DS_WORK.Phrase`  a
join `project-id.DS_WORK.StringList` b
ON a.Phrase LIKE '%' || b.SearchString || '%' )
SELECT 
a.SearchString,
'[' || a.Phrases || ']' AS Phrases
FROM ( SELECT 
first_batch.SearchString as SearchString,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY first_batch.Phrase) AS rn,
STRING_AGG(first_batch.Phrase)
  OVER (
    PARTITION BY first_batch.Phrase
  ) AS Phrases
FROM first_batch ) AS a
WHERE a.rn = 1
```

If you need to try it on simple query with real data use this:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `table` AS (
  SELECT '1' AS UserId, 'A' AS Name UNION ALL
  SELECT '1' AS UserId, 'B' AS Name UNION ALL
  SELECT '1' AS UserId, 'C' AS Name UNION ALL
  SELECT '2' AS UserId, 'A' AS Name UNION ALL
  SELECT '3' AS UserId, 'B' AS Name
)
SELECT a.UserId, a.Name FROM (SELECT
UserId,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId) AS rn,
STRING_AGG(Name)
  OVER (
    PARTITION BY UserId
  ) AS Name
from `table`) as a
where a.rn=1
```

If window functions do not help you can compose your query similar as following with using distinct and nested select

```
#standardSQL
WITH `table` AS (
  SELECT '1' AS UserId, 'A' AS Name UNION ALL
  SELECT '1' AS UserId, 'B' AS Name UNION ALL
  SELECT '1' AS UserId, 'C' AS Name UNION ALL
  SELECT '2' AS UserId, 'A' AS Name UNION ALL
  SELECT '3' AS UserId, 'B' AS Name
)
SELECT a.UserId,
(SELECT STRING_AGG(Name) from `table` as t where a.UserId = t.UserId) as Names
FROM (SELECT
DISTINCT UserId,
from `table`) as a
```

Comment: This query actually takes more CPU than group one.  "Query exceeded resource limits. 16258.025859160658 CPU seconds were used, and this query must use less than 9200.0 CPU seconds."

Comment: that means some of the first_batch.Phrase group is too big. I added one more way to my answer how to write such query with using of DISTINCT and nested SELECT. Can you rewrite your query in such way? Is it work?